# Downloading video files with NSURLSession downloadTask is very slow

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

While downloading video files by using NSURLSession downloadTask is very slow, I have created the download manager by using NSURLSession backgroundSession to download Images & Videos synchronously as per the requirement.

But,

1. Three Images around 5MB getting downloaded with in 5-10sec
2. Video files downloading in the speed of 16 - 30KBPS, even with the faster networks such as 20MBPS, 100MBPS & 500MBPS.
3. Same video files getting fast download in Browser with respective network speed.
4. So network could not be the issue

Please suggest me what could be the issue, any one.

May this problem with NSURLSession?

Thanks a ton in Advance.

Comment: There's no slowdown problem in NSURLSession that I'm aware of. Background downloads take place when Apple's operating system thinks that it's a good time.  It does this to maximize the energy use of the battery powered device.  You don't have control over background downloading.  Frankly, this should not be an issue.  If your app is in the background, then no one can tell if it's downloaded or not.  When it moves to the foreground, the download will then pick up at foreground speed.  You might want to incorporate the very good AFNetworking library to make sure it's not your code.

Comment: If you really mean hundreds of megabytes per second and not megabits, bear in mind that the download tasks write to a file, which limits their speed to probably 30-40 megabytes per second as an upper bound.  If you mean 100 megabits per second... are you sure the network connection all the way to the server is that fast?

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot for your time,  I agreed the network limits will be there, I guess our server has to support the same speed in maximum time because that's dedicate server for large Videos, also when parallel downloading the files from Mobile and Browser, download speed in Mobile was 16kbps where as in Browser 2mbps for 20Mbps network.

Comment: I wonder if your ISP is throttling your app's requests based on your User-Agent string (or failing to whitelist it).  You might try a data task in the foreground and see if you get the same results.